# How to resolve VS 2010 SP1 installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I try to install visual studio 2010 SP1, it gives following error.I selected the vs_setup.msi from installation folder and tried with re-install vs 2010 and system restarting but problem is still exist.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mount your Visual Studio (RTM) ISO into a virtual DVD drive, click on `Browse` and selected the `vs_setup.msi` on the mounted ISO. Now Windows can pick all files required to install the Sp1.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I got this solved. I installed vs2010 sp1 offline installer.